# markov decision process / stochastic optimal control solver c/c++

Tags: c++, c, optimization, mathematical-optimization, markov-models

i am looking for solver for solver/optimizer for markov decision process / 
stochastic optimal control problem (see also [Sequential Decision Making
under Uncertainty](http://www.pitt.edu/~schaefer/papers/MDPTutorial.pdf).

The problem is described by set of differential equations but it my by discretized in time.

```
d w / dt = u f(w) + z * w
d R / dt = (1-u) g(w)
```

where f(.),g(t) is some function, z is a random variable with normal/log normal/power law probability distribution, u is a control which is contained in [0,1].  u may change in time.

Optimization criteria may be mean revenue in the final time T:

```
max_u E[R(T)]_z
```

I am looking for library, something similar to http://nicky.vanforeest.com/probability/mdp/mdp.html but in c/c++, that solve this kind of problems.

Comment: I don't know who up-voted this question, even though he didn't show any sign of effort.He just ask us to write the code in `"c/c++"` even if `c` and `c++` are different languages.

Comment: "solver/optimizer" i.e. library which implements routines that solve this type of problems (like solver for PDE, eigenvalue problems etc...) not some one who solve the problem.